# Query problem with array_to_json()

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, json

Considering my basic knowledge of PostgreSQL I am unable to find out why my second statement for where clause `(record->'details'->>'amount')::numeric(19,2) = 2.99` is not working with current query. Idea is to send common filter from UI for header and details and when I am trying to filter to inner array `details Json column` its not giving me a exact result though it has some data within it

```
WITH t as (select row_to_json(rr)::jsonb as record
from (
       select (
                select row_to_json(row)
                from (
                       select 
                             c.customer_id,
                             c.first_name,
                             c.last_name,
                             c.email,                   
                             count(*) total, 
                             sum(p2.amount) total_amount
                       from payment p2
                       where p2.customer_id = c.customer_id
                     ) row
              ) as header,
              (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(row)))
                from (
                       select
                             amount,
                             payment_date                              
                       from payment p1                            
                       where p1.customer_id = c.customer_id
                     ) row
              ) as details
       from customer c
       join payment p on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
     ) rr) 

    SELECT record FROM t 
    where record->'header'->>'customer_id'= '2'
    and (record->'details'->>'amount')::numeric(19,2)= 2.99
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error?  getting back data you don't want?  Not getting data you do want?

Comment: Please always disclose your version of Postgres. (`SELECT version();`) And describe what your query is supposed to achieve. As it stands it is logical and syntactical nonsense.

Comment: @jjanes, not working as in query not returning any data though I have data within that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be performance suicide to first build a huge `jsonb` object from joining two tables, and *then* filter a single record representing an underlying row. You would filter first, of course.

Going out on a limb, this might be what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT to_jsonb(rr) AS record
FROM  (
   SELECT (SELECT to_jsonb(row) FROM  (
              SELECT c.customer_id
                   , c.first_name
                   , c.last_name
                   , c.email                
                   , p3.total
                   , p3.total_amount) h) AS header
        , p3.details
   FROM   customer c
   JOIN   LATERAL (
      SELECT count(*) AS total
           , sum(p2.amount) AS total_amount
           , jsonb_agg(detail) AS details
      FROM  (
         SELECT p.amount
              , (SELECT to_jsonb(d) FROM (SELECT p.amount, p.payment_date) d) AS detail
         FROM   payment p
         WHERE  p.customer_id = c.customer_id
         ) p2
      ) p3 ON p3.total_amount = 2.99   -- here !
   WHERE  customer_id = 2              -- and here !
   ) rr
```

There is no `record->'details'->>'amount'` in your object. There are array elements like `record->'details'->0->>'amount'`, but those make no sense with the `=` operator. So I assumed you are aiming for `total_amount`.

A little less confusing with `jsonb_build_object()`:

```
SELECT to_jsonb(rr) AS record
FROM  (
   SELECT jsonb_build_object('customer_id', c.customer_id
                           , 'first_name', c.first_name
                           , 'last_name', c.last_name
                           , 'email', c.email                
                           , 'total', p3.total
                           , 'total_amount', p3.total_amount) AS header
        , p3.details
   FROM   customer c
   JOIN   LATERAL (
      SELECT count(*) AS total
           , sum(p2.amount) AS total_amount
           , jsonb_agg(detail) AS details
      FROM  (
         SELECT p.amount
              , jsonb_build_object('amount', p.amount
                                 , 'payment_date', p.payment_date) AS detail
         FROM   payment p
         WHERE  p.customer_id = c.customer_id
         ) p2
      ) p3 ON p3.total_amount = 2.99   -- here !
   WHERE  customer_id = 2              -- and here !
   ) rr;
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter both header and details in a same where clause statement?

Comment: looks like the above queries are also not resolving my problem.